# solr complexphrase query ignoring AND clauses

Tags: solr, lucene, datastax

While using complexphrase parser in Solr (4.10) I'm trying to run this query: ((a AND b) OR c) AND D.

The order is important, (A and B) or C should appear before D.

This is my query - `{!complexphrase inOrder=true}title:"((a AND b) OR c) d"~1000`.

The problem is that Solr threat the first AND as OR, and returning all the documents which their title is `(a OR b OR c) AND d`.
What can I do?

Comment: Have you seen any documentation that shows this sort of syntax (`AND` and `OR` within a complex phrase) is supported?  I don't think I have.

Comment: @femtoRgon It's not a documentation but I saw this [blog post](http://yonik.com/solr-4-8-features/) and something more official you can find [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-ComplexPhraseQueryParser). The first sentence is _The ComplexPhraseQParser provides support for wildcards, ORs, etc., inside phrase queries using Lucene's ComplexPhraseQueryParser_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is support for `AND` syntax in the complex phrase query parser.  `OR`s use a [`SpanOr`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/spans/SpanOrQuery.html).  There is no equivalent `SpanAnd` in Lucene.

Even if a `SpanAnd` did exist, I get the feeling it might mean something different than you expect.  An OR is used to match one or the other *at the same position*.  That is, `(A OR B) C` matches "A C" and "B C".  So, this theoretical SpanAnd `(A AND B) C` would have to have both A and B at the same position, just before C.  It is possible to have two terms occupying the same space in the index (with stemmers, synonym filters, etc.), but it's usually not particularly interesting to search for directly.

To achieve what you are looking for, you may need go with something like:  `"a b d"~1000 "c d"~1000`

Expressing this query as you've written it is (roughly) possible through the Lucene SpanQuery API:

```java
SpanQuery abQuery = new SpanNearQuery(new SpanQuery[] {
        new SpanTermQuery(new Term("field", "a")),
        new SpanTermQuery(new Term("field", "b"))
    }, 1000, true);
SpanQuery cQuery = new SpanTermQuery(new Term("field", "c"));
SpanQuery abcQuery = new SpanOrQuery(new SpanQuery[] {
        abQuery,
        cQuery
    });
Query finalQuery = new SpanNearQuery(new SpanQuery[] {
        abcQuery,
        new SpanTermQuery(new Term("field", "d"))
    }, 1000, true);
TopDocs docs = searcher.search(finalQuery, 10);
```

I don't believe the ComplexPhrase parser is quite capable of expressing it, though.  That involves nested SpanNears, which I don't believe that parser supports.

Comment: Is there any other way that you can think of to write this query in Lucene?

Comment: @ashual - Not really, no.  Surround would be the other likely query parser to try, but it doesn't support nesting like this either.

Answer (score 1):

try this: 
`_query_:"{!complexphrase}title:\"A\"" AND _query_:"{!complexphrase}title:\"B\""`